# How to print a certain element in a ChainMap

Tags: python, dictionary, collections

I have a variable `reaction`. It is a `ChainMap` container. This variable has a function `keys()`. This function is used to display all the keys of all the dictionaries in the `ChainMap`. My problem is that I can't print a сertain symbol.

For example: `reaction` variable is:

```
reaction = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

I want to print the second key, that is `2`, but I can't find how to do it

My code:

```
import collections 

# initializing dictionaries 
dic1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2} 

# initializing ChainMap 
chain = collections.ChainMap(dic1) 

# printing chainMap using maps 
print("All the ChainMap contents are : ") 
print(chain.maps) 

# printing keys using keys() 
print("All keys of ChainMap are : ") 
print(list(chain.keys())) 

# printing keys using keys() 
print("All values of ChainMap are : ") 
print(list(chain.values()))
```

Comment: Second key is `b`, not `2` (which is the value). Whats your desired goal?

Comment: There are key() and value. Value is symbol before : and key() after :

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chainmap-in-python/

Comment: @Antonio: The pairs in dictionaries are written as key : value. In your example, reaction['b'] would evaluate to 2 ('b' is the key and 2 is the value), while reaction[2] would throw an exception because there is no key 2 available.

Comment: Ok, but how can i print certain symbol

Comment: print(reaction['b']) will print 2 to the standard output, as the value of reaction with key 'b' is 2